# Tengo el siguiente problema de base de datos

Tags: mysql

```
select  b.num_det , a.num_doc, a.fecha_doc,a.fecha_ref as Fecha_ODSC, a.tipo_doc EDSC, a.num_doc N°_EDSC, a.fecha_ref as Fecha_EDSC, a.moneda MonEDSC,  c.codigo, e.cod_cencos, e.nombre, b.*,  d.cant_compra as cant_recibida, b.cantidad-cant_compra as cant_pendiente 
from docum_enc as a, docum_det as b, productos as c, valor_stock as d, cen_costos as e
where  a.tipo_doc='OC'  
and a.fecha_doc between '2020-11-09' and '2020-11-10'  
and a.docnumreg=b.docnumreg and b.cod_art=c.cod_art 
and d.cod_art=b.cod_art and b.cen_cos=e.cen_costos
```

Al ejecutar me funciona y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quiero agrupar por *cod_art* y aplicar un sum al campo *cant_recibida*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado usar *group by* pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

si pueden ver en esta ultima imagen ordene un poco los campo mas relevantes el campo codigo es el codigo del producto y se repite dos veces porque tiene dos movimientos de stock el cual se ve reflejado en el campo cant_recibido ese es el campo que quiero sumar y agrupar por codigo de producto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en esta ultima imagen intento agrupar por codigo muestra ese error

Comment: Quita las imagenes, explica mejor tu error, y lo que buscas realizar. Ahora mismo solo se que quieres agrupar y sumar, pero no comprendo tu error.

Comment: Hola Jhonathan, favor puedes compartir el Query que tiene error al agrupar, saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido Jhonathan Sanchez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre. NO, todas esas imagenes no se ven ni se entienden!